# Join 2 videos to play at the same time

Tags: ffmpeg

Let's say that I have a `file1.avi` and a `file2.avi`. Each one of these files is the same size, for instance 300x100.

How could I join them, so that both of them would play the first 10 seconds of each video at the same time, one on top of the other, in a 300x200 video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i file1.avi -i file2.avi -filter_complex "[0][1]vstack" -t 10 joined.avi
```

This will stack the videos vertically and play the first 10 seconds of each. Remove the `-t` option if the videos are longer and you wish to extend the output. This command also uses the default parameters to encode the video i.e. codec will be MPEG4 Part 2 (Xvid..). If there's any audio, the track from the first video will be used and encoded as MP3.